# gnuplot isstring function available?

Tags: gnuplot

I am digging in gnuplot script. I am trouble with handling of variables.

My calculated variables sometimes are real , sometimes string ("outrange" etc).

Next step i want to put them into a long string after some calculations, but I cannot do.

For example,

```
my_return_var="1.2 3.4 5 outrange 9 20 3 4"
newstr=""
do for [tmp in my_return_var]{
    newstr=newstr.sprintf("%7.3f ",tmp*4)
    print newstr
}
```

Because fourth value is "outrange", sprintf return error:  f_sprintf: attempt to print string value with numeric format

Thus, if gnuplot has a function checking if the input is string or not and return 1 or 0, like isstring() in C, I could skip this.

Is there any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gnuplot doesn't have a string checking function. But you can do string comparison with `eq` or `ne` to check against a fixed placeholder:

```
my_return_var="1.2 3.4 5 outrange 9 20 3 4"
newstr=""
do for [tmp in my_return_var] {
    if (tmp ne "outrange") {
        newstr=newstr.sprintf("%7.3f ",tmp*4)
        print newstr
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is easy and brilliant. I did not imagine.